# Onclick event is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a small problem, so I created a getter from which I get values, I wanted to assign an onclick to the last one, but it didn't work. If I assign the values ​​, as in the commented code, everything works fine, someone can correct me where I make a mistake

```
 <ul class="list">
  <!-- <li class="item">
    <img src="some.img.link" class="list-image" />
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="list-item" value="My Profile"></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <img src="some.img.link" class="list-image" />
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="list-item" value="My Events"></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <img src="some.img.link" class="list-image" />
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="list-item" value="My Orders"></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
  </li>
  <li class="item" onclick={handleLogout}>
    <img src="some.img.link" class="list-image" />
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="list-item" value="Log Out"></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
  </li> -->
  <template for:each={menuData} for:item="el">
    <li class="item" key={el.id}>
      <img src={el.img} class="list-image" />
      <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="list-item" value={el.title}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
  

**JS**
get menuData() {
    return [
        {
            title: 'My Profile',
            img: 'https://salesforce-hcp-prod.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Salesforce/GLOBMX/icons/person.png'
        },
        {
            title: 'My Events',
            img: 'https://salesforce-hcp-prod.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Salesforce/GLOBMX/icons/people.png'
        },
        {
            title: 'My Orders',
            img: 'https://salesforce-hcp-prod.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Salesforce/GLOBMX/icons/bag.png'
        },
        {
            title: 'Log Out',
            img: 'https://salesforce-hcp-prod.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Salesforce/GLOBMX/icons/exit.png',
            onclick: () => this.handleLogout()
        },


    ];
}

handleLogout() {
    const logoutUrl = `${basePath.replace(/\/s$/i, '')}/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=${basePath}`;
    window.open(logoutUrl, '_self');

}
```

Comment: You're not returning any id for the values of menuData.Not entirely sure but as all keys will be the same it might be the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `iterator` and utilize it's `first`/`last` properties to do this.

This can be a little clumsy looking as you can see:

```
<template iterator:it={menuData}>
  <li if:false={it.last} class="item" key={it.value.id}>
    <img src={it.value.img} class="list-image" />
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="list-item" value={it.value.title}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
  </li>
  <li if:true={it.last} onclick={handleLogout} class="item" key={it.value.id}>
    <img src={it.value.img} class="list-image" />
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="list-item" value={it.value.title}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
  </li>
</template>
```

One solution is to mark the item and logout if the title (or something else) matches the expected logout text.

```
<template for:each={menuData} for:item="el">
  <li class="item" key={el.id} data-title={el.title} onclick={handleClick}>
    <img src={el.img} class="list-image" />
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text class="list-item" value={el.title}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
  </li>
</template>
```

JS:

```
handleClick = (e)=>{
  let title = e.currentTarget.dataset.title;
  if (title.toLowerCase() === 'log out'){
    //do your logout stuff
  }
  else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

You could also find the last item in javascript and add the event handler to it in the `renderedCallback`.